# How to decide which framework to use for frontend?

Tags: frontend, web-frontend

I am trying to develop web application but I can't decide which framework to choose for front-end.
I could use Vue.js, Angular, React or Vanilla.js.

What are the parameters we need to consider while choosing front-end technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Stage of your business Your technology stack plays an important role at every stage of your business. If you’re just starting out, your primary goal must be launch the MVP as quickly as possible. Any language/framework/CMS tool that lets you put together a working prototype in the shortest possible time should be a good fit.  WordPress is the ideal choice for a customer facing website or building a landing page as you do not require heavy programming knowledge. If your business is in the finance or banking space that requires security from the onset, opt for Java from the beginning.
2. Project requirement Before choosing any tech stack, understand the requirements of the project. Does your app require real-time functionality, such as a chatbot or live chat? In such cases, go with a tech stack that is good at concurrency, such as Node. If you’re a blogger who requires a functional website to increase conversions, WordPress or Drupal will work best. Is your frontend UI full of complex interactions? Then React or Angular may be good front-end tech stacks. Complete understanding of the project goals and business objectives along with the right selection of tech stack plays an important role in long-term success. Wrong selection may lead to financial loss.
3. Availability of resources The availability of developers who will create your product is one of the most influential factors defining your company's technology stack. Look whether your developers are willing and able to work within your chosen tech stack. Suppose you select a programming language not in common use such as Lisp, you will be hard-pressed to find programmers who know how to use it. If they do, they’ll charge a premium. Pick a tech stack that has a dynamic developer community. Commonly used programming languages will thrive in the near future and as a business owner it is easy for you to add new developers to the team.
4. Development and maintenance cost The technology stack directly influences development cost. There are a couple of factors to consider before picking up the right tech stack:
   The cost of hiring a developer: Developers must be skilled professionals and the cost of hiring them varies based on the technologies they work with. Maintenance cost: The job doesn’t get over with the development completion of the MVP. Take into account the maintenance and upgradation cost. Consider sticking to open source technologies because they are cheaper and can be updated and changed without any restrictions.
5. Time to market Time to market is perhaps the most important for all startups. The faster you develop and launch your application, the more exposure you’ll get. Also, the less the time you spend developing initially, the more time you get to learn from the feedback of the users. Here is a list of the common issues you must consider while choosing a suitable tech stack: Third-party integration: Make sure the technology stack you choose allows third-party integrations, to integrate the features you need into your web or mobile application without reinventing the wheel. Developer availability: To turn your idea into a great web application, you need to have an experienced team of developers that can use the tools you choose and work with you in the long-term. Ask them if they will offer post-launch support. Testing: Make informed decisions based on how easy it would be to run tests on the chosen platform. No software product is developed perfectly the very first time. The chosen tech stack should allow you to fix bugs or tweak features easily without eating up a lot of time.
6. Scalability and security Products require a well-defined scalability matrix that works on both the scenarios either vertically or horizontally. Vertical scalability: lets you add more features on top of the core value proposition of your product. Horizontal scenario: lets you handle increased volume of users and transactions on the platform. Security Always make sure the application is developed keeping the best practices of security and threat mitigation in mind. Run security tests both on client and server side to eliminate the common security threats. The more robust your product is, the easier it becomes to sell in the market. At the end, make a choice that works best for your business. You can choose the technology to go with, based on your business goals, requirements and the resources you can afford.

Answer (score 0):

there are plenty of articles on the internet if you search:

https://medium.com/unicorn-supplies/9-steps-how-to-choose-a-technology-stack-for-your-web-application-a6e302398e55
https://hackernoon.com/how-to-pick-the-right-web-technology-stack-for-your-product-f6d94440af2f
https://www.upwork.com/hiring/for-clients/how-to-choose-a-technology-stack-for-web-application-development/

etc.

For start, choose the technology you know better :)